# Identifying Email Messages by IDs

Tags: outlook

I was wondering if anyone knew whether there is a unique identifier attached to an email that I can use to verify whether emails are the same? I know about the EntryID and PR_SEARCH_KEY, but i need something abit more specific if it exists.

Supposed I forward an email to 3 people. I want to make sure that at most 1 copy of those forwarded emails is added to a database. Is there an identifier that will be shared between those three emails that i can record and use to disallow entry of the other two? Or will I have to add a manual tag somewhere on the email?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is the Message-ID, which all good emailers use. However, not everyone in the world uses it.

Comment: RFC 2882 upgraded "Message-ID" to a SHOULD implement category. These days, it could be argued that mail without a Message-ID SHOULD be discarded, or at least complained about by Jamie's application. http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.html#sec-3.6.4

Comment: How do you actually access that property though? I'm using C# (in outlook 2003) so theres no direct way to get to them. I tried writing a marshalling wrapper to do the go between, but I can't get it to work. What would it's MAPI address be?

Thanks for the help so far

Comment: I don't really use C#, so I can't really answer that. Can you access the raw headers of the email? If so, look for a line that starts "Message-ID".